# What is the meaning of order in B+ Tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree

Recently I was going through B+ Tree and I am not getting the meaning of Order in B+ Tree.

Answer (score 1):

The order refers to the size of each node, order 5 would tell you that there is 5 pointers/keys and 4 values in each inner node.

Comment: 4 values? the order 5 is not the pointer + keys? values did not store in the inner node, it store in the leaf node.@Michael Fouché